# It shows that CF grammar is ambiguous

Tags: context-free, tree-grammars

Let $G$ be the CF grammar that has the production rules:
$S \to aS | aSbS | c$. Show that $G$ is ambiguous.

I thought of proving it by representing the string $aacbc$ but I don't know if it is correct as a solution:

$aS \to aaSbS \to aacbS \to aacbc$

$aSbS \to aaSbS \to aacbS \to aacbc$

Comment: Why do you think your solution is not correct? It looks fine.

Comment: Because in the text of my book it says "we claim that a grammar generates an ambiguous string if the string has two different derivation trees, not two distinct derivations. In fact, two derivations might differ simply in the order in which the variables are substituted but retain the same derivation tree", but I don't quite understand what he means by this

Comment: Can you tell if the derivation sequences that you wrote correspond to different derivation trees? Yes, we can have for a single derivation tree different corresponding derivation sequences up to the order from where we choose to derive. Start by drawing the derivation trees that correspond to the derivation sequences you wrote. Then, check wether they're different. Also, check if for one of them you have two different derivation sequences.

Comment: So to say that a grammar is ambiguous I only need to find two derivation trees for a string? But if I choose different rules, will I have different derivation trees anyway?

Comment: Yes, two derivation trees. For the second question, it depends by what you mean by "different rules". If you choose a rule that was never chosen in the other derivation, then the trees will be different. If you chose the same rules but in different order, then you might get the same tree. For example, from $aaSbS$ you can start by deriving $c$ from the first $S$ and then $c$ from the second $S$, or you can derive c from the second $S$ , and after derive $c$ from the first $S$ -- this gives the same tree.

Comment: Ah ok so probably the book means the order of substitution of non-terminal variables, whether to substitute them first from the right or from the left. I thank you for your time

Comment: Can you draw the derivation tree(s)?